# Stuck on Paper-Scissors-Rock game

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, switch-statement

While loop iterates two times every time, and CPU only scores point when choosing 'S' for scissors. Another question is, how do I make it toupper and where do I add that function? I have to use characters 'r','s', and 'p', instead of 1,2,3 to accept user input. Not sure how to proceed to fix this

````
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include<time.h> 

int main () {

   char player1;
   int player2;
   int userScore = 0, cpuScore = 0;
   player2 = rand ( ) % 3 + 1;
   srand ((int) time (NULL));

int count = 0;
while(count <= 10) {
  printf("\nEnter p for Paper, r for rock, or S for scissor: ");
  scanf("%c", &player1);
   switch(player1) {
      case 'P' :
       if(player1 == 'P' && player2 == 1) {
         printf("Draw!");
         break;
       } else if(player1 == 'P' && player2 == 2) {
         userScore++;
         printf("User won this one!");
         break;
       } else {
         cpuScore++;
         printf("CPU won this one!");
         break;
       }
      case 'R': 
         if(player1 == 'R' && player2 == 2) {
         printf("Draw!");
         break;
       } else if(player1 == 'R' && player2 == 3) {
         userScore++;
         printf("User won this one!");
         break;
       } else {
         cpuScore++;
         printf("CPU won this one!");
         break;
       }
      case 'S':
        if(player1 == 'S' && player2 == 3) {
         printf("Draw!");
         break;
       } else if(player1 == 'S' && player2 == 1) {
         userScore++;
         break;
         printf("User won this one!");
       } else {
         cpuScore++;
         printf("CPU won this one!");
         break;
       }
      default :
         printf("\nInvalid Input");
         break;
   }
   printf("\nUser Score: %d", userScore);
   printf("\nCPU Score: %d", cpuScore);
   count++;
}
   if(userScore == cpuScore) {
     printf("\nDraw game!");
   } else if(userScore > cpuScore) {
     printf("\nYou win!");
   } else {
     printf("\nCPU wins!");
   }
   return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Please apply consistent indentation.

Comment: You need to call `srand()` _before_ `rand()` otherwise you will get the same `player2` every time.

Comment: @xing :  Since there is only one request for input and there is no game loop, preceding `%c` with a space does nothing useful.  If the game were iterated, it only solves a subset of `scanf()` issues.  The user might enter `"paper"` or `"pp"` for example, which would defeat your method.

Comment: @xing Yes my error - poor indenting in the code does not make it obvious.  My point was that the leading space only consumes whitespace, not other junk.  See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you fix it by making it far less complicated. The winner of Rock-Paper-Scissors can be determined arithmetically.

It is simpler to compare like for like, and using integer values allows a simpler arithmetic solution.  Also arithmetically it is simpler to use 0,1,2 rather than 1,2,3.  So first transform the user input to 0,1,2:

```
#define INVALID_SELECTION sizeof(rps)
static const char rps[] = {'r', 'p', 's'} ;
int human = INVALID_SELECTION ;

while( human == INVALID_SELECTION )
{
    printf("\nEnter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: ");

    char ch = 0 ;
    scanf("%c", &ch ) ;
    while( ch != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' ) ;

    for( human = 0; 
         human < INVALID_SELECTION && tolower(ch) != rps[human] ; 
         human++ )
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

The computer play should then be determined thus :

```
srand( (int)time(NULL) ) ;
int computer = rand() % 3 ;
```

though note that you need only call `srand()` once, so if you put the game in a loop to repeat play, the `srand()` call should appear *before* the repeat loop.

You can then report the play thus:

```
static const char* play_lookup[] = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" } ;
printf( "Human played %s\n", play_lookup[human] ) ;
printf( "Computer played %s\n", play_lookup[computer] ) ;
```

Then `human` and `computer` are directly and arithmetically comparable such that:

```
int battle = human - computer ;
if( battle < 0 ) battle += 3 ;
switch( battle )
{
    case 0 : printf( "Draw!\n" ) ; break ;
    case 1 : printf( "Human wins!\n" ) ; break ;
    case 2 : printf( "Computer wins!\n" ) ; break ;
}
```

or (credit to @HAL9000):

```
int battle = ((human - computer) + 3) % 3 ;
switch( battle )
...
```

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    // Randomize
    srand( (int)time(NULL) ) ;
    
    // Repeat play indefinitely
    for(;;)
    {
        #define INVALID_SELECTION sizeof(rps)
        static const char rps[] = {'r', 'p', 's'} ;
        int human = INVALID_SELECTION ;
        
        // While human input is not one of R,P,S,r,p or s...
        while( human == INVALID_SELECTION )
        {
            printf("\nEnter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: ");
        
            char ch = 0 ;
            scanf("%c", &ch ) ;
            while( ch != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' ) ;
        
            // Transform input to one of 0,1,2 (for R,P,S respectively)
            for( human = 0; 
                 human < INVALID_SELECTION && tolower(ch) != rps[human] ; 
                 human++ )
            {
                // do nothing
            }
        }

        // Get computer's play    
        int computer = rand() % 3 ;
    
        // Report human and computer plays in full text
        static const char* play_lookup[] = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" } ;
        printf( "Human played %s\n", play_lookup[human] ) ;
        printf( "Computer played %s\n", play_lookup[computer] ) ;
    
        // Calculate and report result
        int battle = ((human - computer) + 3) % 3 ;
        switch( battle )
        {
            case 0 : printf( "Draw!\n" ) ; break ;
            case 1 : printf( "Human wins!\n" ) ; break ;
            case 2 : printf( "Computer wins!\n" ) ; break ;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: r
Human played Rock
Computer played Rock
Draw!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: r
Human played Rock
Computer played Scissors
Human wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: r
Human played Rock
Computer played Rock
Draw!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: r
Human played Rock
Computer played Scissors
Human wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: r
Human played Rock
Computer played Paper
Computer wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: p
Human played Paper
Computer played Paper
Draw!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: p
Human played Paper
Computer played Scissors
Computer wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: p
Human played Paper
Computer played Rock
Human wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Human played Scissors
Computer played Scissors
Draw!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Human played Scissors
Computer played Paper
Human wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Human played Scissors
Computer played Paper
Human wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Human played Scissors
Computer played Scissors
Draw!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Human played Scissors
Computer played Rock
Computer wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: R
Human played Rock
Computer played Scissors
Human wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: P
Human played Paper
Computer played Paper
Draw!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: S
Human played Scissors
Computer played Paper
Human wins!

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: xx

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: yy

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: zz

Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors:
```

Comment: The obvious compare-each-entry requires `O(n^2)` space; your arithmetically comparable solution is `O(n)` and much more elegant. +1

Comment: @Neil Thanks, although I was not aiming for reduced _computational_ complexity as such.  Rather succinctness, readability and maintainability.

Comment: Just to be "that guy", but you coud do `battle +=3; battle %= 3 ;` rather than  `if( battle < 0 ) battle += 3 ;`. One less branch for those tight corners.

Comment: @HAL9000 to be sure there are "equivalents".  I work in embedded systems, where often avoiding a mod or div is preferable to avoiding a branch, so my solution is from habit born if necessity.  I do however prefer your solution.

Comment: @HAL9000 - added with credit.  Play at https://onlinegdb.com/HJe6RAoX8

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main () {
   char player1;
   int player2;
   int userScore = 0, cpuScore = 0;
   srand ((int) time (NULL));
   int count = 0;
   while(count != 10) {
       printf("Enter p for Paper, r for rock, or S for scissor:\n");
       fgets(&player1, 80, stdin);
       player2 = rand ( ) % 4;
       if(player1 == 'P' && player2 == 1) {
         printf("Draw!\n");
       }if(player1 == 'P' && player2 == 2) {
        userScore++;
        printf("User won this one!\n");
       }if(player1 == 'P' && player2 == 3){
         cpuScore++;
         printf("CPU won this one!\n");
       }
       if(player1 == 'R' && player2 == 2) {
         printf("Draw!\n");
       }if(player1 == 'R' && player2 == 3) {
         userScore++;
         printf("User won this one!\n");
       }if(player1 == 'R' && player2 == 1){
         cpuScore++;
         printf("CPU won this one!\n");
       }
       if(player1 == 'S' && player2 == 3) {
         printf("Draw!\n");
       }if(player1 == 'S' && player2 == 1) {
         userScore++;
         printf("User won this one!\n");
       }if(player1 == 'S' && player2 == 2){
         cpuScore++;
         printf("CPU won this one!\n");
       }
       if(player1!='S' || player1!='R' || player1!='P'){
         printf("Invalid Input\n");
       }
    printf("User Score: %d\n", userScore);
    printf("CPU Score: %d\n", cpuScore);
    count++;
}
   if(userScore == cpuScore) {
     printf("Draw game!\n");
   } else if(userScore > cpuScore) {
     printf("You win!\n");
   } else {
     printf("CPU wins!\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I should also add that this program is sensitive. For example, inputting 'r' will not work but 'R' will. Change this at your discretion.

Comment: Turns out good but it continues to print "Invalid Input" and do you know how I can make it to where it will accept character 'r' and 'R'. Where do I add the toupper function?

Comment: Well, to make it accept 'R' and 'r' you would just have to write something like: if((player1 == 'R' || player1=='r') && player2 == 2){

Comment: You would have to do this for all conditionals.

Comment: If you wanted to use a toupper function, then you would take the value of the player1 input and send it to the function right after it was given. So it would be sent after the fgets(&player1, 80, stdin);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting `player2` outside the loop, and not updating it; it will constantly be the same. Instead of converting it to an intermediary value by `toupper`, this is probably a typical case where converting it directly to an `enum` would be appropriate. Instead of a `switch` with `if`, this shrinks your problem space to 3 values, which fits in a lookup-table easily.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> /* `printf` requires this. */
#include <time.h>

/* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro just because I don't want to type. */
#define CHOICE(X)  X(ROCK), X(PAPER), X(SCISSORS)
#define OUTCOME(X) X(LOSS), X(TIE), X(WIN)
#define NAME(A) A
#define STR(A) #A
enum Choice { CHOICE(NAME) };
static const char *const choice_names[] = { CHOICE(STR) };
enum Outcome { OUTCOME(NAME) };
static const char *const outcome_names[] = { OUTCOME(STR) };
static enum Outcome choice_outcomes[][3] = {
    { TIE, LOSS,  WIN },
    { WIN,  TIE, LOSS },
    { LOSS, WIN,  TIE }
};

int main(void) { /* <- `void` should be used to prototype. */
    char input;
    enum Choice player1, player2;
    int score[] = { 0, 0, 0 }; /* <- Replace `cpuScore` and `userScore`. */
    int count = 0;

    srand ((int) time (NULL)); /* <- `srand` should precede `rand`. */

    while(count <= 10) {
        printf("\nEnter p for Paper, r for rock, or S for scissor: ");
        /* Ignores whitespace, (_viz_ enter); breaks on error, (_eg_ EOF.) */
        if(scanf(" %c", &input) != 1) break;
        /* Convert it to `player1` immediately. */
        switch(input) {
        case 'r': case 'R':
            player1 = ROCK; break;
        case 'p': case 'P':
            player1 = PAPER; break;
        case 's': case 'S':
            player1 = SCISSORS; break;
        default:
            printf("Unexpected input, '%c'.\n", input); continue;
        }
        player2 = rand() % 3;
        printf("User choses %s _vs_ Cpu choses %s: %s.\n",
            choice_names[player1], choice_names[player2],
            outcome_names[choice_outcomes[player1][player2]]);
        score[choice_outcomes[player1][player2]]++;
        printf("User Score: %d\n", score[WIN]);
        printf("CPU Score: %d\n", score[LOSS]);
        printf("Ties: %d\n", score[TIE]);
        count++;
    }
    /* One of the places was the `scanf` break, so check, (unlikely.) */
    if(ferror(stdin)) { perror("stdin"); return 1; }

    /* Print the winner. */
    if(score[WIN] == score[LOSS]) {
        printf("Draw game!\n");
    } else if(score[WIN] > score[LOSS]) {
        printf("You win!\n");
    } else {
        printf("CPU wins!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also put `userScore` and `cpuScore` into an array indexed by `enum Outcome`.