# Why do my break / if statement not working?

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison, break

im making a rock paper scissor game, with a rematch option until the player has played enough, if the player want to stop playing, he just have to type "N" to exit the loop, but mine wont seems to work, it just keep rematching regardless of the player input

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int regles(char joueur, char cpu) // rules of rock paper scissor "p" = rock, "f" = paper, c = scissor
{
    if (joueur == cpu) // if player == cpu its a draw
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if ((joueur == 'p' && cpu == 'c') || (joueur == 'f' && cpu == 'p') || (joueur == 'c' && cpu == 'f')) // player victory case
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if ((joueur == 'p' && cpu == 'f') || (joueur == 'f' && cpu == 'c') || (joueur == 'c' && cpu == 'p')) // player defeat case
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int f_random(int max) // using s_rand and time to have a random number each time for the cpu to use to play
{
    time_t seconds;
    int result;
    seconds = time(0);
    srand(seconds);
    result = rand() % max;
    return result;
}

char f_jeu_cpu() // cpu "choosing" his move
{
    int n;
    char cpu;
    n = f_random(100);
    if (n < 33)
    {
        cpu = 'p';
    }
    else if (n > 33 && n < 66)
    {
        cpu = 'f';
    }
    else
    {
        cpu = 'c';
    }
    
    return cpu;
}

char f_jeu_joueur() // player input
{
    while ( getchar ( ) != '\n' );
    char joueur;
    printf("Entrez p pour PIERRE, f pour FEUILLE, c pour CISEAUX ");
    scanf("%c", &joueur);
    return joueur;
}

int f_affichage(int resultat, char joueur, char cpu) // result display
{
    if (resultat == 2)
    {
        printf("egalité\n"); // draw
    }
    else if (resultat == 0)
    {
        printf("vous remportez la partie\n"); // player win
    }
    else
    {
         printf("Vous perdez la partie\n"); // player defeat
    }
    printf("Vous avez choisi %c et l'ordi a choisi %c \n", joueur, cpu); // display player and cpu choice
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    char joueur, cpu;
    
    int resultat;
    
    int affichage;
    
    char choix;
    
    while(1) // while loop for a rematch
    {
        printf("Voulez vous rejouer?\n"); // ask for a rematch
        scanf("%c", &choix);
        if (&choix == "N")
        {
        break;
        }
        
        joueur = f_jeu_joueur();
    
        cpu = f_jeu_cpu();

        resultat = regles(joueur, cpu);
    
        affichage = f_affichage(resultat, joueur, cpu);
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: `if (&choix == "N")` -> `if (choix == 'N')` You probably want to use `" %c"` as your format string to read characters as well, assuming you want it to skip leading whitespace.

Comment: You should only call `srand()` once not every time you need a random number.  Your play solution is bizarre; CPU will select "Ciseaux" for values 33 and 67 to 99 (34% chance); clearly the human should select "Pierre" every time!  Apart from that there is a far simper solution to this game.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309066/stuck-on-paper-scissors-rock-game/60311165#60311165, where if the plays are represented by values 0,1,2, then the result is `battle = ((human - computer) + 3) % 3 ;`, where `battle` = 0 to 2 for draw, human win, computer win respectively.

Answer (score 2):

This if statement

```
if (&choix == "N")
```

compares two pointers: the pointer to the object `choix` and the pointer to the first character of the string literal `"N"`. As the string literal and the object `choix` declared like

```
char choix;
```

occupy different extent of memory then the if statement always evaluates to logical false.

You need just to write

```
if ( choix == 'N')
```

Also I advice in the call of `scanf` to use the following format string

```
scanf(" %c", &choix);
```

See the blank before the conversion specifier `%c`.

Pay attention to that the function `f_jeu_cpu` can return the uninitialized variable `cpu` when `n` is equal to `33`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i didnt thinked about that !